# nvida card (rtx 3050 laptop) not working (x11 or wayland)

Tags: nvidia, graphics, xorg, wayland, 23.04

I'm on Ubuntu 23.04 with a hybrid graphic system (amd radeon integrated GPU + nvidia rtx 3050 laptop dedicated GPU). I use the 525 nvidia drivers (the one recommended by Ubuntu when doing `ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`). The thing is when I switch to wayland my nvidia GPU isn't detected anymore while it all works fine on X11.
Does anybody have an idea for where it could come from and if it's fixable ?
Thanks in advance !

EDIT : Actually I think the nvidia GPU just doesn't work : when on x11 in hybrid mode, launching a game with the "use the dedicated GPU" option the games just crashes.

Comment: I think this is a known weakness of Wayland, unless it have been addressed and solved in more recent versions of Ubuntu like 23.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I just re installed Ubuntu and now it works fine. I think I just messed up my drivers when I tried to deal with another problem (did `sudo apt install fuse` which broke my system) a few days ago.

Answer (score 0):

The file /usr/share/applications/steam.desktop has a line PrefersNonDefaultGPU=false (or true), try editing the file (with sudo) and change the value.

From an X session, run

```
xrandr --listproviders
```

A hybrid laptop should use the dedicated GPU for the work and offload the display to the integrated GPU.  Sometimes this assignment gets reversed.  No idea how, but you can force things back with the environment variables:

```
__NV_PRIME_RENDER_OFFLOAD=1 __GLX_VENDOR_LIBRARY_NAME=nvidia <progtorun>
```

Under Wayland, the xrandr won't show much, but the environment variables still work.\

I don't use prime to switch GPUs, I just try to use the Nvidia, so ensure your nvidia-settings profile is set to performance.  Look at the power settings too, I thought selecting "performance" there might affect this GPU assignment too, but not so sure now.

Comment: Thanks ! Though my problem didn't come from that switching to performance mode in the nvidia settings really improved my experience